# How to extract from a string?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I write a query to extract something like that:

If I have:

```
John Snow
Ananana Bacarara
```

I want to get the result:

```
John
Ananana
```

I tried a lot of things with `substr()` but still didn't get to a solution..

Comment: You want all characters until first <space> is found? Which dbms are you using?

Comment: So you have a full name field and you want to select the first name?

Comment: I want to make it in PL/SQL, but it's basically a querry.. i just need the idea

Comment: Yes, suppose we have Name Surname.. i want to extract only the Name until the space

Comment: Post all the attempts you have made and explain specifically how each one was incorrect.

Comment: I tried with SUBSTR(name,1,length(name)/2).. but it doesn't work on every example.. cause the lenght may be too short or longer

Comment: So what happens if someone has 2 first names? do you just take the 'first' first name or do you need both?

Comment: Supposing you have "Anna Nicole Smith"?

Comment: Do you even know what PL/SQL means?

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` string functions.

**Query**

```
SELECT SUBSTR(name, 1, INSTR(name, ' ') - 1) as first_name
FROM your_table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `INSTR()` to identify the index position of the space in the column, then substring up to, but not including, that space:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(column, 1, INSTR(column, ' ')-1)
FROM yourTable
```

From your failed attempt, it appears you were trying to take half the string, hoping that you would end up with just the first name.  Instead, use the position of the space in the name to separate the first and last names.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with regular expressions, REGEXEXP_SUBSTR will also do what you are asking for:

```
  1* select regexp_substr('&parm','\w*') from dual
Enter value for parm: John Snow
old:select regexp_substr('&parm','\w*') from dual
new:select regexp_substr('John Snow','\w*') from dual

REGE
----
John

SQL> /
Enter value for parm: Ananana Bacarara
old:select regexp_substr('&parm','\w*') from dual
new:select regexp_substr('Ananana Bacarara','\w*') from dual

REGEXP_
-------
Ananana

SQL>
```